# Map doesn't load second time i click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kendo-ui, openstreetmap

I want to show my open street map on a Kendo UI window. At First time on click the map shows, but after that it doesn't load. Even if I use google map the same result. After searching on google, I have found that we can not initialize map more than one time. I have tried in different ways, but it doesn't work. May be my approach was not good. Here 'is my code

```
var data=' ';

function createMap() {
    data = $("#map").kendoMap({
        center: [23.7099, 90.4071],
        zoom: 15,
        layers: [
            {
                type: "tile",
                urlTemplate: "http://#= subdomain #.tile2.opencyclemap.org/transport/#= zoom #/#= x #/#= y #.png",
                subdomains: ["a", "b", "c"],
                attribution: "&copy; <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a>."
            }
        ]
    });   
}

function showMap(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wnd = $("#Map").data("kendoWindow");
    createMap();
    wnd.content(data);
    wnd.center().open();

}
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Map")
  .Title("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker'></span> Map of the road")
  .Visible(false)
  .Modal(true)
  .Draggable(true)
  .Width(635)
)
```

ShowMap fire on user click

[image: When i click first time]
[image: When i click more than one]

Comment: if thats your actual code, then change `#Map` to `#map`, might be typo ;)

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas #Map is the kendo window id  and #map is placeholder for map<div id="map"></div> . They are not related to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this at the end of the function

```
$("#map").data("kendoMap").resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to redraw the map. You can do this using the following code:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This will make the map refresh, fixing your issue.